# how to enable laravel 4 gzip?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4, gzip

I have two .htaccess file in my laravel 4 project,one in root and another one in public folder.I copied this line in first:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

because I I don't wanna type /public after domain name,and It works,but I copy the code for enabling gzip in second .htaccess it causes 500 internal server error.
I copy below lines from [gziptest.com/faq](http://www.gziptest.com/faq) and also I tried many other files but none of them worked for me.

```
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-js
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

   # Highest 9 - Lowest 1
   DeflateCompressionLevel 9

   # Skip browsers with known problems
   BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
   BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
   BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

please help me?

Comment: OP you haven't chosen any answer as a solution, did any of them manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem and then I went and tried something from the folks at [html5 boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/dist/.htaccess) and it worked for me.

Here's the snippet:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    # https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/pushing-beyond-gzipping-25601.html

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Map certain file types to the specified encoding type in order to
    # make Apache serve them with the appropriate `Content-Encoding` HTTP
    # response header (this will NOT make Apache compress them!).

    # If the following file types wouldn't be served without the appropriate
    # `Content-Enable` HTTP response header, client applications (e.g.:
    # browsers) wouldn't know that they first need to uncompress the response,
    # and thus, wouldn't be able to understand the content.

    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addencoding

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip              svgz
    </IfModule>

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.

    # IMPORTANT: For Apache versions below 2.3.7 you don't need to enable
    # `mod_filter` and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` & `</IfModule>`
    # lines as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives.

    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                      "application/javascript" \
                                      "application/json" \
                                      "application/ld+json" \
                                      "application/manifest+json" \
                                      "application/rdf+xml" \
                                      "application/rss+xml" \
                                      "application/schema+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                      "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                      "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                      "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                      "application/xml" \
                                      "font/opentype" \
                                      "image/svg+xml" \
                                      "image/x-icon" \
                                      "text/cache-manifest" \
                                      "text/css" \
                                      "text/html" \
                                      "text/javascript" \
                                      "text/plain" \
                                      "text/vtt" \
                                      "text/x-component" \
                                      "text/xml"
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is really helped, Onething more to add, You have to enable 2 module mod_deflate and mod_filter

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of an old question, so this probably won't be much help to the OP, but I came across this while dealing with the same issue (500 internal server error after modifying the .htaccess) and thought it might be worth mentioning in case anyone else winds up here with the same problem. After checking the error log, I found this error:

> ...Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', perhaps misspelled or defined
>   by a module not included in the server configuration

So after Googling that, I found [this in the Apache docs on upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html#commonproblems), where it says:

> Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', perhaps misspelled or defined
>   by a module not included in the server configuration -
>   AddOutputFilterByType has moved from the core to mod_filter, which
>   must be loaded.

I am running 2.4, so I checked httpd.conf and uncommented `LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so` and that did the trick.

Comment: And in case the `mod_filter` is not activated, but you don't want the 500 internal server error...`, just wrap the `AddOutputFilterByType` in `<IfModule mod_filter.c></IfModule>`